# not able to install tweepy using pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, tweepy

```
enter code hereFile "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 193, in clobber
os.makedirs(destsubdir)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/ad/.pip/pip.log

Comment: ad@ad:~$ pip install tweepy
Downloading/unpacking tweepy
  Downloading tweepy-3.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking requests>=2.4.3 (from tweepy)
Downloading/unpacking six>=1.7.3 (from tweepy)
  Downloading six-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking requests-oauthlib>=0.4.1 (from tweepy)
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy' Storing debug log for failure in /home/ad/.pip/pip.log

Comment: If you google this error you will notice that there are tons of stackoverflow threads on this issue.

Comment: @cel providing with a link or even flagging it would've helped. Anyway, I know I might get flamed for this but I run `sudo` when I install `tweepy` and it works.

Comment: @Leb, noone is going to flame you for providing an answer.  However finding the solution is very easy with a minimum amount of effort in this case. It just requires googling and clicking through the first few hits. Actually I did not link to an answer, because everyone recommends `sudo pip install`. IMO, this is a bad habit and going for a virtualenv is the  right way here. However finding an answer that uses a virtualenv is rather tricky.

Comment: @cel I 100% agree with you about googling the information, this is a problem in SO that requires a great deal of attention but lacks in priority. Not to go *too far* off-topic, I've actually been criticized for using `sudo` in such situations for the same reason you mentioned "bad habit, and unecessary". In my view it's quick and gets the job done, so to each his own. If the person deems it unsafe, there are longer methods as you mentioned to fix `[Errno 13]`

Comment: hi thak you for your reply. i did sudo but it did not work for me. i am serching for other options as well on google. even git does not work because when i type python tweepy.py install....it says it des not have the rights to do this...then even chmod does not help.